# NHibernate [MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document: iMed.Models.Device.hbm.xml]

Tags: nhibernate, model-view-controller

I'm currently trying to use nhibernate with MVC 3.5.

I have placed my nhibernate.cfg.xml in my root to my MVC project.
Please see screen grab of project. Both xml files are set to Embedded Resource.

I have a DeviceRepository.cs That has a method that uses Device.cs for the persistence.

Here is the xml of nhibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!-- properties -->
<property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property>
<property name="connection.connection_string">Server=192.168.1.5;Database=imed_development;User ID=root;Password=lights337</property>
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

<!-- mapping files -->
<mapping resource="iMed.Models.Device.hbm.xml" assembly="iMed" />
```

Here is the xml of Device.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="iMed.Models.Device" table="devices">
    <id name="Id" column="ID" type="int">
      <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Identifier" column="identifier" type="String"></property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I'm currently getting a

```
{"Could not compile the mapping document: iMed.Models.Device.hbm.xml"}
{"persistent class iMed.Models.Device not found"}
```

I'm pretty new to this, any input would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks in advance...

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

its saying you are referencing a class in your mapping that doesn't exist.